# PHP redundantly setting default value for property

Tags: php

I have a simple question.
I have a class, imagine a car Class. I have a functional API, classic CRUD over this resource, which is also an Entity -> meaning I have such table in database;
Do I have to explicitelly assign default value 0 the property, when I do it in constructor? Will this value ever be evaluated or is it just redundant initialization? Thanks

```
class Car
{
  private int $id;
  ....
  private int $driveModes = 0; <--- is this necessary?

  public function __construct(....., int $driveModes = 0){
  .....
    $this->driveModes = $driveModes;
  }

  ....
  getters and setters

}
```

Comment: I'd say it's redundant, since the constructor defaults it to that anyway if no value is provided

Comment: I would say, no it's not necessary since you will always set the values in the constructor anyway, but I don't see it hurting either. Imho, it makes it much easier to just glance at the class to know what the defaults are. The down side is that you need to remember updating both if you change the default.